# Java calling a method to print class lists

Tags: java, method-call

Really need to know how to call this method in another class thnx

```
public static void printClass(){
    System.out.println(subjectName + " Class List");

    for(Student i : studentList)
    {   
        Student.printStudent();
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommmend to start with a tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html

Comment: What is the name of the class which contains this static method?

Comment: have them all on my desktop and no dice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a `static` method (*class method*), you can call it in two ways:

```
NameOfClass.printClass();
```

or

```
NameOfClass someInstance = new NameOfClass(...); // create instance
someInstance.printClass();
```

**Why?** Because *class methods* doesn't need an instance of the class to be called, so you can call it with only using the name of the class (first way). But Java also provides the feature to call the `static` method using an instance of the class.

Comment: I think you are going to cause the OP more trouble, as this method is using field variables which may or not be intialised

Comment: I just answered the question. He has not provided further information. If he commented something, I would edit with the necessary changes/explanations.

Comment: and yes more problems have occurred.

Answer (score 1):

You can call a `static` method like this:

```
ClassName.methodName();
```

So, e.g., if you're class is called `SomeClass`:

```
SomeClass.printClass();
```